# How to make wait-notify-one faster or is there an alternative way to implement wait-notify function?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, condition-variable

In my c++ program, I have an object `X`, when one thread wants to handle `X`, it must wait for the 'X->state' being set. During this thread is waiting (by call `wait()`), aother thread can modify 'X->state'. When one thread modifies 'X->state', it calls `notify_one()`. In this case, I find that the time from one thread modifies 'X->state' and another thread awake from waiting is very high, about 20-50us (depends on how many threads running on the machine). It means that when one thread modifies the state and notifies, another thread still needs a long time to awake from waiting. Is there any way to reduce this time, or is there any other ways to implement the same functions.

Comment: I think the overhead you see is the overhead of thread context switching. One way to address this is to have the signaler directly execute the continuation of the waiter on the signaling thread. I.e. instead of thread 1 doing `cv.wait(); continue_working();` and thread 2 doing `cv.notify_one();`, have thread 2 do the `continue_working()` directly. Note that this transformation can be quite complicated depending on the nature of `continue_working()`.

Comment: Instead of using wait/notify, your waiting thread could just spin on an atomic variable and the notifying thread just needs to update the variable. This will be fast if you don't oversubscribe your CPUs. You don't indicate what hardware your using or what your workload is like but if you're utilizing hyperthreading, (i.e. using more logical threads than there are physical threads), you probably want to use spin loop hints such as the `_mm_pause()` intrinsic for x86, `__yield()` intrinsic on ARM, etc.

Comment: The machine has 2 CPUs, each has 8 core. Each thread commits requests, and a coordinator will choose a thread as a leader during the threads who commit requests at this time window. The leader thread can handle all the requests in batch, and others just wait. When the leader finishes the batch, it notifies others, then others can return.

Comment: If waiting thread just spins instead of using wait/notify, it can improve performance when the number of threads is less than CPU cores. If we have more threads, it can not work well. `continue_working()` is just return this function call. Is there any way to do `continue_working()` in leader thread.

Comment: Is there a reason why only one thread is handling the requests in the batch? Can the work be divided up amongst the threads?

Comment: Each thread commits an IO request. If they handle their own IO separately, the IO latency is very high because of the contention. If we choose a thread as a leader to handle the IOs in batch and others are waiting for the leader to finish the requests, the IO latency can be slower.

Comment: What kind of I/O operations are being performed? Is it necessary for the other threads to wait or could work be continued in parallel with the leader handling the batch? What does the leader election look like?

Comment: Each thread appends data to a file. When only when the data is synced to the device, the thread can return. If each thread only appends its own data to this file, there are multiple threads writing to file at the same time, which causes longer latency. But if one of these threads is chosen to be a leader (actually anyone can be a leader, e.g. we can select the first one to be a leader), leader writes all of the data in a batch and others wait leader to finish the write and then others can return. The synchronized write must be guaranteed.